# Is k-means clustering guaranteed to converge if using Manhattan distance?

Tags: normed-spaces, computational-geometry, least-squares, clustering

The [k-means algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is an iterative clustering algorithm that partitions the data points into K clusters (with centroids {$\mu_1, ... , \mu_k$}, minimizing the [Sum-of-Squared-Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares):

$$
SSE = \sum_{i=1}^K \sum_{x \in S_i} ||x -\mu_i  ||^2
$$

K-means uses [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (L2 [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))) as the distance function , that is $D_{euclidean}= \|(X-Y)\|^2=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + ... + (x_n-y_n)^2}$.

**My question**: If I use **[Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (L1 norm)** is used instead of euclidean, is there any guarantee that the algorithm still minimizes SSE? If not, which function is minimized if L1 norm is used?

EDIT: Below is a picture that demonstrates how a 2-D space is partitioned using L1 and L2 norms:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $L_1$ norm has a big flaw:

try to apply $K$-clustering in a 2d space, with 2 centroids. When you have to say which points are near to which centroid there's a high grade of uncertainty, since the surface wiht the same distance from both centroids has infinite (lebesgue) measure. (on the contrary, euclidean distance has only a line, so a 0-measure set).

So the algorithm isn't really well-defined, and it could not finish with any function

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, the distance of each point to each of the centroids is not uncertain, as long as the axes are fixed (and not rotated).
Is it right? ( Sorry, I am not a mathematician :(  )

Comment: Once you fix the axes, the distance is not uncertain, but if you have a point that has the same dstance from both centroid, in which cluster do you put it? I'm saying that with L1 norm, there are a lot of point that are at the same distance from both centroids

Comment: I edited the post to show an example. As you see in the picture, bot L2 and L1 norms will partition the space like a  Voronoi diagram. Is there any difference between the two metrics? As I see in the picture, the probability that a point drops exactly on the border of two clusters in L1 voronoi seems to be equal to that of L2 norm. Isn't it?

Comment: try to colour with black all the points that has more then one minimum, end expand the domain